# How to rewrite `install -T /dev/null xxx`

Tags: echo

I am trying to write in one command the following 2 ones:

```
install -m 0755 -T /dev/null filename
echo "file content" > filename
```

Is that possible? Is there any way to avoid the `-T /dev/null` for "touching" a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a single command, but a single line (and `filename` is created with the correct mode and content), on shells which support process substitution:

```
install -m 0755 <(echo "file content") filename
```